# How to add a new transponder / key to a Daihatsu immobiliser

Tags: obd-ii, immobilizer, daihatsu, program

How can I add a new key to a Daihatsu immobiliser?

The key I have has a Texas 4C transponder, and is used in the Daihatsu Copen and Daihatsu YRV (to name just two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the black "master" key that came with your Daihatsu, adding new keys is simple. You will need to have all your keys ready, as these steps will remove all keys from the immobiliser ECU with the exception of the black master key.

These steps will work for the Daihatsu Copen (pre 2013) and the Daihatsu YRV

- Connect the terminal T to Terminal E on the DLC / OBDII port
- Insert the master key into the ignition
- Turn on the ignition (do not turn over the car)
- Turn off the ignition
- Remove the key from the ignition
- (Withinn 10s) turn on the ignition using the sub key
- Turn off the ignition
- Remove the key from the ignition
- Repeats steps 6-8 using another key
- After the final key removal, wait 30 seconds.
- Remove the OBDII short

Terminal T is OBDII pin 13 and terminal E is OBDII pin 4

[This youtube video covers this also](http://youtu.be/N96wMYQN_DM)